# How can I remove the left header link from a Jekyll website?

Tags: html, css, markdown, jekyll

I'm building my own website with Jekyll support and I wanna remove only the link on the left header. How can I do this?

As an example I want to remove the linked placed on "Blog Title" in https://niklasbuschmann.github.io/contrast/ and continue with everything as it is.

Thank you!

from mywebsite.github.io/_layouts/default.html :

```html
<header>
  <a href="{{ "/" | relative_url }}" class="title">{{ site.title | escape }}</a>
  {% include menu.html menu=pages %}
</header>
```

Comment: This depends on the theme. The page you link to uses https://github.com/niklasbuschmann/contrast, and the link is in the default template [here](https://github.com/niklasbuschmann/contrast/blob/8fbf024fa63bbf70e2902c3b5c0189515a1f9ef0/_layouts/default.html#L31).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I've tried to remove the "escape" but it didn't work.

Comment: `escape` is just a Liquid filter to URL-escape a string. You'd have to copy the template file into your site and modify it to override the theme. Are you using `remote-theme`? It's hard to diagnose without seeing any of your configuration.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I forked so I guess it looks exactly the same.

Comment: You should be able to delete the entire `<a>` line to get rid of the link.

Comment: did not work as I expected but I will try to fix it, thank you @BenjaminW.